# How to get Solr Facets of an item that is the child of a document field

Tags: c#, .net, solr, solrnet

The Solr search module I'm working on is somehow special. So instead of having standard Solr documents like Project, Product .., I have one document whose fields are *id*, *id_item*, *source_item*, *field_name* as shown below :

```
public class ItemFound
{
    [SolrUniqueKey("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [SolrField("id_item")]
    public string id_item { get; set; }

    [SolrField("source_item")]
    public string source_item { get; set; }

    [SolrField("field_name")]
    public string field_name { get; set; }

}
```

- The source_item field refers to the type of the item (Project, **Product** ..)
- The field_name field refers to the field's name of an item (Product : **brand**)
- The id_item field refers to the value of the source item (Product **PD105**)
- The id field brings together all the informations above ( **PD105-FIELDBRAND** )

When we want to show the results, we retrieve the solr query result, then we do a mapping with our database to get the values matching our query result.

The UI would show a table for each source type (*Product*, *Project*..) with a list of products/projects/.. including the keyword query.

So my problem is: how can I get the facets of a field (Brand for example), knowing that I can get the facets of field_name (the result would be : **Brand (10), size (55), ...**) but I want to have (**Apple (10), Nike (15), ..**).

That's it. Hope I described well my issue.

Comment: Which field contains these values? Facets are calculated based on the filters given for the query, so if you want to limit it to a subset of documents, those filters will be active as well (i.e. to just those that have `Product` in `source_item` etc.

Comment: There is no solr field containing these values (Apple, Nike..). In the Solr document, I have the **field_name** field whose facets show **Brand (10), size (55), ...**.

Comment: So how are you going to generate facets for terms that are not in the index?

Comment: Yeah, I think it isn't possible. I was wondering if there's a solution to do that without touching the solr document because in that case, I will have to modify all the code doing the indexation.  Well, I will try to add a field in that document that contains the value the field (in my context, like **brand** field).

Comment: If you don't have the values (or an id of the value), you can't generate a facet without actually having data to generate the facet from. Solr can't pull values you might want up from thin air.

Comment: Yes totally true.  Thanks Mats, I will update you with my work.